# Modular Application Zend Framework 1.10 not see class in default folder model

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have next folder structure zf version 1.10

```
/application
 /config
  application.ini
 /Forms
 /Layouts
 /modules
    /default
     /controllers
     /models
      manufactur.php
     /view
     bootstrap.php
 bootrstrap.php
```

apllication.ini have next content

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/"
resources.modules = ""
```

/modules/bootstrap.php

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
        protected function _initAutoload()
        {
                $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
                'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules/default' ,
                'namespace'=> '',
                'resourceTypes'=>array(
                'form'=>array(
                'path'=>'Forms',
                'namespace'=>'Form')))
                );
                 }
}
```

/modules/default/bootstrap.php

```
class Default_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```

/default/models/manufactur.php

```
class Manufactur extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'manufacturers';
    protected $_primary = 'id';

}
```

When i in any controller trying $a = new Manufactur()
i see Error not find class

when i before call use include 'path/to/manufactur.php'
all work fine

Any idea why it can be ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add your models folder to the `include_path` or register that path with an autoloader.

Comment: to any modular i must register one more include path ?

Comment: Well, the autoloader needs to know where to look for it. It has to know *somehow*.

Comment: If i have 5 part how i must registry 5 path 
it basic structure mvc i controllers and view work fine but wy wrong with models ?

Where i must register new path ? in mudules/bootstrap.php or default/bootstrap.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved
No need any

```
You will have to add your models folder to the include_path or register that path with an autoloader.
```

just prefix in class name like

```
Default_Model_Manufactur
```

and all work fine